# simple ADD/ADC ARM assemlby fails

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, arm

I have the following C and ASM version of the (supposedly) same code. What it does is load 2 128bit ints represented by 2 64bit ints each to registers (first 4*lower 32bit, then 4*higher 32bit) and `ADD`/`ADC` to them. It is simple enough code and the ARM/ST manuals actually give the same example with 96bit (3 `ADD`/`ADC`s).

For simple calls both versions work (repeatedly adding `(1 << x++)` or 1..x). But for the longer testsuite the ARM assembly fails (board hangs). ATM I have no ability to trap/debug that and cannot use any `printf()` or the likes to find the test failing, which is irrelevant anyways, because there must be some basic fault in the ASM version, as the C version works as expected.

I don't get it, it's simple enough and very close to the C assembly output (sans branching). I tried the "memory" constraint (shouldn't be needed), I tried saving the carry between lower and upper 64bit in a register and adding that later, using `ADD(C).W`, alignment, using two `LDR`/`STR` instead of `LDRD`/`STRD`, etc.. I assume the board faults because some addition goes wrong and results in a divide by 0 or something like that.
The GCC ASM is below and uses similar basic technique, so I don't see the problem.

I'm really just looking for the fastest way to do the add, not to fix that code specifically. It's a shame you have to use constant register names because there is no constraint for specifying `rX` and `rX+1`. Also it's impossible to use as many registers as GCC as it will run out of them during compilation.

```
typedef struct I128 {
    int64_t high;
    uint64_t low;
} I128;

I128 I128add(I128 a, const I128 b) {
#if defined(USEASM) && defined(ARMx)
    __asm(
            "LDRD %%r2, %%r3, %[alo]\n"
            "LDRD %%r4, %%r5, %[blo]\n"
            "ADDS %%r2, %%r2, %%r4\n"
            "ADCS %%r3, %%r3, %%r5\n"
            "STRD %%r2, %%r3, %[alo]\n"

            "LDRD %%r2, %%r3, %[ahi]\n"
            "LDRD %%r4, %%r5, %[bhi]\n"
            "ADCS %%r2, %%r2, %%r4\n"
            "ADC %%r3, %%r3, %%r5\n"
            "STRD %%r2, %%r3, %[ahi]\n"
            : [alo] "+m" (a.low), [ahi] "+m" (a.high)
            : [blo] "m" (b.low), [bhi] "m" (b.high)
            : "r2", "r3", "r4", "r5", "cc"
            );
    return a;
#else
    // faster to use temp than saving low and adding to a directly
    I128 r = {a.high + b.high, a.low + b.low};
    // check for overflow of low 64 bits, add carry to high
    // avoid conditionals
    //r.high += r.low < a.low || r.low < b.low;
    // actually gcc produces faster code with conditionals
    if(r.low < a.low || r.low < b.low) ++r.high;
    return r;
}
```

GCC C version using " armv7m-none-eabi-gcc-4.7.2 -O3 -ggdb -fomit-frame-pointer -falign-functions=16 -std=gnu99 -march=armv7e-m":

```
b082        sub sp, #8
e92d 0ff0   stmdb   sp!, {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, sl, fp}
a908        add r1, sp, #32
e881 000c   stmia.w r1, {r2, r3}
e9dd 890e   ldrd    r8, r9, [sp, #56]   ; 0x38
e9dd 670a   ldrd    r6, r7, [sp, #40]   ; 0x28
e9dd 2308   ldrd    r2, r3, [sp, #32]
e9dd 450c   ldrd    r4, r5, [sp, #48]   ; 0x30
eb16 0a08   adds.w  sl, r6, r8
eb47 0b09   adc.w   fp, r7, r9
1912        adds    r2, r2, r4
eb43 0305   adc.w   r3, r3, r5
45bb        cmp fp, r7
bf08        it  eq
45b2        cmpeq   sl, r6
d303        bcc.n   8012c9a <I128add+0x3a>
45cb        cmp fp, r9
bf08        it  eq
45c2        cmpeq   sl, r8
d204        bcs.n   8012ca4 <I128add+0x44>
2401        movs    r4, #1
2500        movs    r5, #0
1912        adds    r2, r2, r4
eb43 0305   adc.w   r3, r3, r5
e9c0 2300   strd    r2, r3, [r0]
e9c0 ab02   strd    sl, fp, [r0, #8]
e8bd 0ff0   ldmia.w sp!, {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, sl, fp}
b002        add sp, #8
4770        bx  lr
```

My ASM version that fails:

```
b082        sub sp, #8                                                                                  
b430        push    {r4, r5}                                                                            
a902        add r1, sp, #8                                                                              
e881 000c   stmia.w r1, {r2, r3}                                                                        
e9dd 2304   ldrd    r2, r3, [sp, #16]                                                                   
e9dd 4508   ldrd    r4, r5, [sp, #32]                                                                   
1912        adds    r2, r2, r4                                                                          
416b        adcs    r3, r5                                                                              
e9cd 2304   strd    r2, r3, [sp, #16]                                                                   
e9dd 2302   ldrd    r2, r3, [sp, #8]                                                                    
e9dd 4506   ldrd    r4, r5, [sp, #24]                                                                   
4162        adcs    r2, r4                                                                              
eb43 0305   adc.w   r3, r3, r5                                                                          
e9cd 2302   strd    r2, r3, [sp, #8]                                                                    
4604        mov r4, r0                                                                                  
c90f        ldmia   r1, {r0, r1, r2, r3}                                                                
e884 000f   stmia.w r4, {r0, r1, r2, r3}                                                                
4620        mov r0, r4                                                                                  
bc30        pop {r4, r5}                                                                                
b002        add sp, #8                                                                                  
4770        bx  lr
```

Comment: What kind of values go wrong? I'd give it some "sensitive" values (those that cause carryover), and see what comes out. I'm sure it's very obvious once you spot it, but right now I can't.

Comment: Compile with -O2 at least.

Comment: using adcs instead of adc on that last one would save you another halfword of instruction.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: I don't know ATM. As I wrote I can successfully add 1 << x++, which will create overflows after 17 iterations etc. and it all works. I think I may have found the test that fails and it MAY have something to do with negative numbers, though the above test works with that. Digging futher...

Comment: @auselen: it is at -O3 already

Comment: @dwelch: thanks, didn't spot that! I guessed that not using S (no flags update) would be faster, but once it works, I will try

Comment: the original thumb instructions always update the flags (arm versions have an s) the thumb2 extensions (32 bits instead of 16) allow the choice (costing in this case a 32 bit instruction instead of a 16 bit just to not have flags)

Answer (score 1):

I am not getting a hang from your code, but it isnt working either, not sure why.  But it was very easy to patch the compiler generated code to handle the carry:

```
I128 I128add(I128 a, const I128 b) {

    I128 r = {a.high + b.high, a.low + b.low};
    return r;
}
```

becomes

```
000001e4 <I128add>:
 1e4:   b082        sub sp, #8
 1e6:   b4f0        push    {r4, r5, r6, r7}
 1e8:   e9dd 4506   ldrd    r4, r5, [sp, #24]
 1ec:   a904        add r1, sp, #16
 1ee:   e881 000c   stmia.w r1, {r2, r3}
 1f2:   e9dd 230a   ldrd    r2, r3, [sp, #40]   ; 0x28
 1f6:   1912        adds    r2, r2, r4
 1f8:   eb43 0305   adc.w   r3, r3, r5
 1fc:   e9dd 6704   ldrd    r6, r7, [sp, #16]
 200:   e9dd 4508   ldrd    r4, r5, [sp, #32]
 204:   1936        adds    r6, r6, r4
 206:   eb47 0705   adc.w   r7, r7, r5
 20a:   e9c0 6700   strd    r6, r7, [r0]
 20e:   e9c0 2302   strd    r2, r3, [r0, #8]
 212:   bcf0        pop {r4, r5, r6, r7}
 214:   b002        add sp, #8
 216:   4770        bx  lr
```

fixed up the adds

```
.thumb_func
.globl test2
test2:
    sub sp, #8
    push    {r4, r5, r6, r7}
    ldrd    r4, r5, [sp, #24]
    add r1, sp, #16
    stmia r1, {r2, r3}
    ldrd    r2, r3, [sp, #40]
    add r2, r4
    adc r3, r5
    ldrd    r6, r7, [sp, #16]
    ldrd    r4, r5, [sp, #32]
    adc r6, r4
    adc r7, r5
    strd    r6, r7, [r0]
    strd    r2, r3, [r0, #8]
    pop {r4, r5, r6, r7}
    add sp, #8
    bx  lr
```

final result

```
00000024 <test2>:
  24:   b082        sub sp, #8
  26:   b4f0        push    {r4, r5, r6, r7}
  28:   e9dd 4506   ldrd    r4, r5, [sp, #24]
  2c:   a904        add r1, sp, #16
  2e:   c10c        stmia   r1!, {r2, r3}
  30:   e9dd 230a   ldrd    r2, r3, [sp, #40]   ; 0x28
  34:   1912        adds    r2, r2, r4
  36:   416b        adcs    r3, r5
  38:   e9dd 6704   ldrd    r6, r7, [sp, #16]
  3c:   e9dd 4508   ldrd    r4, r5, [sp, #32]
  40:   4166        adcs    r6, r4
  42:   416f        adcs    r7, r5
  44:   e9c0 6700   strd    r6, r7, [r0]
  48:   e9c0 2302   strd    r2, r3, [r0, #8]
  4c:   bcf0        pop {r4, r5, r6, r7}
  4e:   b002        add sp, #8
  50:   4770        bx  lr
```

Notice the fewer number of thumb2 instructions, unless you are on a cortex-A that has thumb2 support, those fetches from flash (cortex-m) are (can be) slow.  I see you are trying to save the push and pop of two more registers but you cost yourself more fetches.  You could take the above and still re-arrange the loads and stores and save those two registers.

minimal testing so far. printfs show the upper words adding, where I didnt see that with your code.  I am stilll trying to unwind the calling convention (please document your code more for us), looks like r0 is prepped by the caller to place the result, rest is on the stack.  I am using a stellaris launchpad (cortex-m4).